# Issue Trying To Get Button Border to Animate on Click

Tags: silverlight, animation, button, silverlight-4.0

I'm trying to animate the border of a button, but having trouble getting it to work.  Here's the XAML I setup:

```
<Button x:Name="Btn">
    <Button.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.Click">
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard Duration="100" AutoReverse="True"
                            Storyboard.TargetName="Btn"                                     
                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                    <ColorAnimation To="Yellow" />
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
    </Button.Triggers>
</Button>
```

I'm getting this error:

```
Failed to assign to property 'System.Windows.EventTrigger.RoutedEvent'. [Line: 17 Position: 30]
```

Any idea why?  Total noob at this.  I'm using Silverlight 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Silverlight only supports the `Loaded` event in an event trigger.  For this sort of thing you need to be looking into Visual State Manager.

The Button already supports a Visual State called "Pressed".  However in order to change the buttons visual behaviour you need to first copy its default template and place it in a static resource.

You can get a copy of the default style used for button [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc278069%28v=VS.95%29.aspx).  Lets assume you give this a `x:Key` of "MyButtonStyle".

You would add your `ColorAnimation` to the existing `Storyboard` for the "Pressed" `VisualState`.

Then your button xaml should be:

```
<Button Style="{StaticResource MyButtonStyle}" Content="Click Me" />
```